# Downcasting and Linq

Tags: c#, linq, casting

I have a base class called LabFileBase.  I have constructed a List and have added my derived classes to it.  I want to search the List for a particular object based on a key I've defined.  The problem I'm having is how do you downcast in a LINQ expression?

Here is some sample code:

```
public abstract class LabFileBase
{
}

public class Sample1 : LabFileBase
{    
    public string ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    //..
}

public class Sample2 : LabFileBase
{    
    public string ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    //..
}
```

I want to search for a particular Sample2 type, but I need to downcast if i used a regular foreach loop like this:

```
foreach(var s in processedFiles)  //processedFiles is a List<LabFileBase>
     if (s is Sample2)
         var found = s as Sample2;
             if (found.ID = ID && found.Name == "Thing I'm looking for")
                  //do extra work
```

I would much rather have something like this:

```
var result = processedFiles.Select(s => s.ID == SomeID && s.Name == SomeName);
```

Is this possible and what syntactic punctuation is involved, or is the `foreach` my only option because of the different objects.  Sample1 and Sample2 only have ID and Name as the same fields.

EDIT: Thanks to all for your support and suggestions, I've entered almost everything into the backlog to implement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To elaborate on Jon's answer, `OfType` is almost certainly the correct operator if you aren't willing to put these fields into your base class.  For example:

```
foreach(var s in processedFiles.OfType<Sample2>())
    if(s.ID == ID && s.Name == "Thing I'm looking for")
        // whatever

foreach(var s in processedFiles.OfType<Sample1>())
    if(s.ID == ID && s.Name == "Some other thing")
        // and so on
```

Answer (score 6):

Why not put `ID` and `Name` into the base class? Then you don't need any downcasting.

If you *do* need casting though, the [`Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) and [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) operators may be helpful to you. Each transforms a sequence into a sequence of the specified type: `Cast` assumes that each element *is* the right type (and throws an exception if that's not the case); `OfType` works more like the C# `as` operator, only returning elements which happen to be the right type and ignoring others.

Comment: seq.OfType<MyFavType>() works like seq.Where(el => el is MyFavType).

Comment: @Jon: I will definitely consider moving ID and Name to the base class.  The more I think about it, they really belong there.

Comment: @Justice: Not quite, because it *also* ends up with a sequence of the target type. It's like seq.Where(...).Cast<...>()

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.  In addition to Jon Skeet's (which is better than this option) note you could try a more manual alternative.  Add an additional property containing an identifier for the type of object it is.

```
public abstract class LabFileBase
{
    public string LabFileObjectType { get; }
    public string ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}


public class Sample1 : LabFileBase
{    
    public string LabFileObjectType { get { return "Sample1"; } }
    //..
}

public class Sample2 : LabFileBase
{    
    public string LabFileObjectType { get { return "Sample2"; } }
    //..
}
```

Then you could query against that property as well:

```
var result = processedFiles.Select(s => s.ID == SomeID && s.Name == SomeName && s.LabFileObjectType == "Sample2");
```

Comment: If you want to do the test in the code, why not just use "&& s is Sample1" though?

Comment: You probably would.  I'm saying there's an alternative from your example.  That's definitely more proper.